# Business Intelligence setup from MS SQL Server or Visual studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, business-intelligence, bids, sql-server-data-tools

Short question, I hope the answer is will be also short.

I'm a starting BI developer and we make a lot of use of Microsoft SQL Server and SQL Server Data tools (SSDT, previously BIDS). SSDT is a Visual Studio shell with components catered towards BI-centric solutions. I've always installed SSDT from a SQL Server installation.

I'm now doing a Visual Studio 2012 installation and notice an option to install SSDT. A quick search on Google only yielded a difference that SQL Server 2012 installs Visual Studio 2010 shell instead of 2012. Is there any other difference in installing SSDT from SQL Server or from Visual Studio?

Any and all help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm a starting BI-developer and we make allot of use of Microsoft SQL
>   Server and SQL Server Data tools (SSDT, previously BIDS).

Ah. No. SSDT and BIDS are not the same. SSDT are a plugin into visual studio for SQL Server development, adding mostly the SQL Server Database Project which allows versioning and development of sql code in visual studio (as in: Stored procedures, table schemata etc.). BIDS is the visual studio version for - Analytics service, Integration Services and Reporting Services.

And SQL Server BIDS is most of the time built on an older version - for the 2012 Shell IIRC you need the 2014 server..... and the concurrent modern version of VS is 2013.

BIDS is NOT SSDT.